# How to revoke gnupg public key without private key?

Tags: security, encryption, gnupg, keyrings, seahorse

Long story short I have an key generated with seahorse and mistakenly deleted it from my system. I do remember passphrase but I don't have this key anywhere on my system. Scanned trough Ask Ubuntu but couldn't find any aplicabile solution on similar issue.

However public key is still updated on keyring servers and I would like to revoke it. Since I have no revocation certificate and I can't get hold of private key (only public key is available from keyservers which I imported to seahorse) I have no idea how to accomplish it.

Spent some time searching for solution acros net, various manuals and so on, but so far no luck.

`gpg --list-secret-keys` -> returns no output at all.
`gpg --list-keys` -> returns public key info
`gpg --gen-revoke *user-id*` -> returns -> `gpg: secret key *user-id* not found: eof`

gpg (GnuPG) version 1.4.11.

Anyone able to suggest a solution?

Comment: The question is down-voted? Could the person explain why? I believe question is pretty clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real way of revoking this key without your original private keys.  You should keep your private key and revocation key stored off system for such cases like this.

Something I've learned early on in playing with PGP/GnuPG.

Create a new key with a text description saying something like "As of

Comment: yeah lesson learned